# Python: finding a particular list item and replacing

Tags: python, list

I tried to look for the solution to this question by perusing the forum but many of the explanations provided are too advanced for me and was wondering if there were a simpler method.

So my question is:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

In `my_list`, I would like to replace all even numbers with an "x".

Is there method where I can just go through a loop and replace them?

Ok, so I was hoping there'd be a simple method like a my_list.replace function but realized there wasn't. So here is the context in which I need to locate and replace:

```
def censor(text, word):
    string = text.split()
    for n in range(len(string)):
        if string[n] == word:
            string[n] == "*" * len(word)

    return string

print censor("hi bob how are you bob", "bob")
```

So in this program I'm trying to replace the "bob" in the phrase to asterisks in accordance to the length of the word bob. But I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Instead the output I'm getting is the same phrase. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a list comprehension (if you wanted to have a more elaborate replacement at some point later) you could loop through it and edit each value in turn if necessary:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if not my_list[i] % 2:
        my_list[i] = 'x'
```

It's not as clean as a comprehension though.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = ['x' if i % 2 == 0 else i for i in my_list]
```

Yes, this still uses a loop, but you need to scan all values for the even numbers *anyway*.

Answer (score 0):

To "just go through the loop and replace them", you could use:

```
for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if not item % 2:
        my_list[index] = "x"
```

A list comprehension is neater, but will build a new list rather than modifying the old one - which you need will depend on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

To offer another alternative, we also could use [map](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map):

```
map(lambda n: 'x' if n%2==0 else n, my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most concise:

```
map(lambda i: 'x' if i % 2 ==0 else i, my_list)
```

**Out[17]: [1, 'x', 3, 'x', 5, 'x']**

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, may I ask what map and lambda does?